# Converting GIF to SWF in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, converters, gif

So I wanted to convert a gif file to swf format, but without using an exe file (there's a bunch available as free downloads). I would like to make this in PHP/Flex if possible. I know php can execute linux commands, which could be a way to go (there are tools for linux), but I was wondering if there is a library for flex that can do so - which would effectively let someone else's computer do it on client side :)

Anyone got some experience with this?

Thx

Comment: You want to convert a GIF to SWF but on client side? Why not convert it to SWF before sending it to client side?

Comment: Well, it's not a requirement... I'm just wondering how to do it. I would like to allow user upload a gif and let him download it / get it as swf.

Comment: Whatever tool or library you will use, you need to embed the gif file in the produced swf and for this you will likely need a compiler.

Comment: Is there some reason a client side solution is preferred to a server side? Server side is probably going to be more reliable, even if you can find some method of doing this client side (which would probably need AIR anyway). It's kind of a strange requirement - gif/swf are sort of apple/orange-ish. Maybe step back and re-examine your requirements, or expand on what your true end goal is if you need suggestions.

Comment: actually, i was simply thinking how this would be solved... actually, my initial idea was to use something like swftools (http://www.swftools.org/) and then let user upload a file, convert it using php exec() and simply return the file. however, i still wanted to consider other options, i.e. doing it client side. i guess this discussion gave me an answer. it would be great if someone could form it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [as3gif](https://github.com/audreyt/as3gif) library allows you to display GIF images in Flash applications.

An approach would be to export the resulting DisplayObject to a ByteArray.

```
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
data.writeObject(gif);
```

You can send the raw data to a server or let the user save the file (at least with AIR).

Comment: looks like this would result in user saving the gif file and I'l like to have it other way around -> user uploads gif and gets swf in return. Or I got you wrong?

Comment: You got me wrong. I didn't try, but it should work the way I described. ByteArray.writeObject() allows you to export DisplayObjects as SWF binaries.

Comment: will try... thank you. i'm also considering very seriously to go with server side anyways, but for fun...